# How to properly parse DateTime string

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, datetimeoffset

I've got input date time strings which look like this: `2015-01-28 17:55:43`. The problem is that they are in UTC+8 (or some other shift). I need those strings parsed and processed properly into UTC, regardless of the timezone where the software runs.
My problem is that `DateTime.Parse` returns local time, not UTC time, and I don't see a way to specify shift when parsing the string.
My current solution to this looks something like this:

`add.LastUpdatedTime = new DateTime((DateTime.Parse(text) - new TimeSpan(0, 8, 0, 0)).Ticks,DateTimeKind.Utc);`

This is ugly, and I'm not sure that it will work well in all circumstances.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `add.LastUpdatedTime = (DateTime.Parse(text)).AddHours(-8) ?`

Comment: @AlexAnderson this will yield local time, not UTC time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that you have a local time and an offset, I'd suggest representing that in `DateTimeOffset`. So:

```
DateTime localTime = DateTime.ParseExact(...);
DateTimeOffset offsetTime = new DateTimeOffset(localTime, offset);
```

Then you still know the local time, but you can get the UTC equivalent when you want it. Basically it preserves all the information you have.

As an alternative, you could use [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) which represents the same information in `OffsetDateTime`. You'd use a `LocalDateTimePattern` to parse the value to a `LocalDateTime`, then use the `WithOffset` method to convert to an appropriate `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: You are missing a name part, "`Offset`", in you `new` expression (constructor invocation).

Comment: I more or less withdraw my answer and +1 @JonSkeet's ... we use [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) at my day job, and have never looked back.

Answer (score 0):

Write a sample program, and output the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("o"));
```

Look at that format, and use it as a template for patching up the string times coming in. For even more viable string options, look at [**DateTime.ToString Method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ... I'll bet some variant on there will work out for you (e.g., play around with a format having "zzz" on the end, which will generate the UTC offset for a local time, e.g., "HH:mm:ss.ffffzzz" as shown in the page linked).

Also look at [**DateTime.Parse Method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) in the examples ... notice the string "2008-09-15T09:30:41.7752486-07:00" containing a UTC offset of -7 (America/Denver) indicated as being valid for parsing.

Comment: The question is about parsing, isn't it?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen they're two sides of the same coin: any formatted string output from `DateTime.ToString` is guaranteed to be accepted as valid input coming back into `DateTime.Parse` ... this means you can use all of the `DateTime.ToString` options to explore how you want a string-representation of your times to look so that they'll be valid time strings.